# joining multiple dataframes : Reference column is ambiguous

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have 3 dataframes. Joining column `id` is present exactly once in each dataframe.

- aggregated_df          : ['id', 'country_agg', 'reference_agg', 'activities_agg', 'type_agg', 'is_batch_agg', 'is_stream_agg']

  - <bound method DataFrame.printSchema of DataFrame[id: string, country_agg: array<structkey:string,timestamp:timestamp>, reference_agg: array<structkey:string,timestamp:timestamp>, activities_agg: array<structkey:array<string,timestamp:timestamp>>, type_agg: array<structkey:array<string,timestamp:timestamp>>, is_batch_agg: array<structkey:string,timestamp:timestamp>, is_stream_agg: array<structkey:string,timestamp:timestamp>]>
- activities_exploded_df : ['id', 'activities_details']

  - <bound method DataFrame.printSchema of DataFrame[id: string, activities_details: array<structkey:string,timestamp:timestamp>]>
- type_exploded_df       : ['id', 'type_details']

  - <bound method DataFrame.printSchema of DataFrame[id: string, type_details: array<structkey:string,timestamp:timestamp>]>

**Below join works:** joining just `2 dataframes`

```
 joined_df = aggregated_df.join(
     type_exploded_df, aggregated_df.id == type_exploded_df.id, "left"
 )
```

**Below join fails with error:** joining `3 dataframes`
Error : AnalysisException: [AMBIGUOUS_REFERENCE] Reference `id` is ambiguous, could be: [`id`, `id`].

```
 joined_df = aggregated_df.join(
     type_exploded_df, aggregated_df.id == type_exploded_df.id, "left"
 ).join(
     activities_exploded_df, type_exploded_df.id == activities_exploded_df.id, "left"
 )
```

**Below join works** : joining `3 dataframes`, change joining way to `"id"`

```
joined_df = aggregated_df.join(
    type_exploded_df, "id", "left"
).join(
    activities_exploded_df, "id", "left"
)
```

Also tested with dummy data, same way of joining above which failed in 2nd case above, is working here.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.functions import col


# Create Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('example').getOrCreate()

# Create the first DataFrame
data1 = [(1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'C')]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data1, ['id', 'col1'])

# Create the second DataFrame
data2 = [(1, 'X'), (2, 'Y'), (4, 'Z')]
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, ['id', 'col2'])

# Create the third DataFrame
data3 = [(1, 'M'), (3, 'N'), (4, 'O')]
df3 = spark.createDataFrame(data3, ['id', 'col3'])

joined_df = df1.join(df2, df1.id == df2.id, 'left').join(df3, df1.id == df3.id, 'left')
joined_df.show()
```

**Question** : when I join 3 dataframes (2nd case), join fails with error Reference `id` is ambiguous. Howeever all dataframes just have only single occurence of column `id`. Also same way of join is working with dummy data at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the code in the scenario where
`Below join fails with error: joining 3 dataframes Error : AnalysisException:`  to the below code to see if it fixes the issue:

```
 joined_df = aggregated_df.join(
     type_exploded_df, aggregated_df.id == type_exploded_df.id, "left"
 ).join(
     activities_exploded_df, aggregated_df.id == activities_exploded_df.id, "left"
 )
```

Comment: getting same error : AnalysisException: [AMBIGUOUS_REFERENCE] Reference `id` is ambiguous, could be: [`id`, `id`].